# Delay notification threshold in Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I am using Delay notification threshold in glue job.
I am getting notification on mail after minutes which I pass in glue job.
I am passing filename in job parameter and I want to send it in mail body. I am not able to pass filename in mail body

Quick help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom python shell job to customize your SNS response.
You can use the parameter you have passed.
Here is a sample code for the same,

```
    import boto3
    from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
    # Create a Glue client
    glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["filename"]
    
    # Specify the name of the Glue job
    job_name = 'your_job_name'
    
    # Retrieve the job details
    response = glue_client.get_job_runs(JobName=job_name)
    
    job_run_state = response['JobRuns'][0]['JobRunState']
    
    error_message = response['JobRuns'][0]['ErrorMessage']
    
    logs = job_name+" failed with the following error \n"+error_message+"\n"+args['filename']
    
    subject = job_name+" Failed"
    sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
    # Specify the ARN of the SNS topic
    topic_arn = 'your_arn'
    # Send the logs via email
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn=topic_arn,
        Subject = subject,
        Message=logs
    )
```